# Error in python

Tags: python, nltk

I am trying to simply classify some words for nltk:

```
contains(want) = True positi : negati = 1.7 : 1.0
contains(great) = True positi : negati = 1.7 : 1.0
contains(love) = False negati : positi = 1.4 : 1.0
contains(die) = False positi : negati = 1.2 : 1.0
contains(live) = False negati : positi = 1.2 : 1.0
contains(terrible) = False positi : negati = 1.2 : 1.0
```

However it gives me a syntax error on `positi`.

Comment: I've never seen python syntax like that before.

Comment: Without further context: where you are adding these definitions, what you've imported, what the precise error message you are getting, etc. it is rather difficult to answer this question.

Comment: Dear OP: read a Python tutorial instead of bother people with questions without having read anything about Python and its syntax.  Voting to be closed.

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely catch up on basic python syntax.
I guess what you really want is something like this:

```
if contains('want'): positi, negati = 1.7, 1.0
```

This assigns `1.7` to `positi` and `1.0` to `negati` when `contains('want')` returns a True value.
I'm assuming that `want`, `greater` etc. aren't variable-names here, but should rather be literal strings.